# How to transfer Excel file data to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

How to create an SQL table with this Excel file and transfer it through SSIS?

I am trying to have the SQL table to be:

| Name | Id | Address | Country | Salary | CompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | 335435 | 123 Fake St | UK | £123 | ACME |
| James | 432434 | 321 Elm St | UK | £120 | ACME |
| Ben | 732434 | PO BOX 123 | UK | £231 | Apple |

I have tried to import the excel file but am not sure how to pass and create `customername` column.

[image: excel]

It's Single Excel Worksheet

Comment: Is that a single worksheet or multiple worksheets in the same excel workbook?

Comment: Did you try Microsoft tutorial? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: There is no `customername` column in your table, and no column in your excel named that either. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: ACME - A3  Apple - A8

Answer (score 0):

if you are using excel connection manager, the datatype for each column will be nvarchar(255) by default. If your db column datatype is varchar, you need to use data conversion task between the source and destination of your data flow task. Please check https://www.sqlshack.com/import-data-from-multiple-excel-files-in-sql-server-tables-using-an-ssis-package/

Comment: I know how to import Excel to sql, My concern is to how to import this type of Excel format.

Comment: Is anyone have idea how to solve the Problem?

Comment: @Sam123 please share with us the correct pattern of your excel file like the cell number where we find the ACME and Apple?

Comment: This is the correct format.